# Configure Server to Initiate Http Keep-Alive

Tags: varnish, http-headers, keepalive

I have a set of clients that aren't including an http keep-alive header in their requests to my server.  If I use something like Varnish to filter the incoming requests and add the keep-alive header to the request before it reaches my web server, can I force the client to use keep-alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keep-alive` is a [hop-by-hop header (RFC 2616)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.5.1), which means the header sent from varnish to backend can be completely independent of the header sent from client to varnish, and must be handled separately. Negotiating keep-alive on the backend will not cause client to keep your connection alive.

Additionally, HTTP/1.1 prefers keep-alive by default without explicit negotiation unless `Connection: close` is specified by client or server (or proxy). You should never have to force `keep-alive` negotiation with a HTTP/1.1 client.